# Have excel file with ODBC link hosted in sharepoint

Tags: excel, odbc, office365

we have a case management system stored with the vendor, and use an excel file on a server locally to access some data, so have an ODBC link setup with security etc.

We are looking to dump the server, and i want to know if there is a way to have the excel file which will be put onto a sharepoint folder have the ODBC link embedded or linked so that a specific machine is not needed to be setup for its use.

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: `Office365` can be directly connected to database without configuring ODBC manually. You can do it from `Data--> Get Data --> From Database`

Comment: Hi @Harun24HR. when i select PostgreSQL it says i need further components installed. Anyway around that?

Comment: You need to install PostGRE ODBC driver but no need manual configuration.

Comment: Ok, so ill get the PostGRE driver installed across the network, then we should be right to go.